# Testing individual microservices in Jhipster

Tags: testing, spring-security, microservices, jhipster

So I have started work in an app built with jhipster. I have made changes to one microservice and want to run only that on my local machine. But I am not able as it gives me a 401 error. Frustrated I simply deleted the securityConfig.java file in app/config and now it keeps hitting me with a login page.

please help.

Comment: Which authentication type did you choose? What kind of tests? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: I used JWT. I realized that JWT tokens are evaluated for each requests, so I generated that and added them to each of my calls and now I have a working way to test them.